# Javascript new Date mismatch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, format

I have been struggling to get this thing working. Here is my issue.

I get the dates from REST API in different formats `(mm-dd-yyyy-timezone, mm-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss, yyyy-mm-dd-timezone, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)` but i have to format it in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I used substring to capture the first 10 characters to get the Datestring by ignoring time/timezone.

During this process i have observed this issue.

```
new Date("08-11-1987") gives me Tue Aug 11 1987 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Where as,

```
new Date("1987-08-11") gives me Mon Aug 10 1987 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Why there is a one day difference while creating the Date object.

Comment: Your server API should not return date as string values. Date should be returned as it is. When a date is serialized it has a specific format and has information about the timezone as well. Javascript engine can use to determine correct date.

Comment: please provide u r code

Comment: @chandermani Thanks for your reply, there are service related issues and its going to take a while to fix it. Meanwhile, we are trying to fix this in UI. I was just curious to understand this JS engine behavior.

Comment: @pankaj Thanks for your reply.Following is my code- $filter("date")(new Date(response.dateOfBirth), "yyyy-MM-dd");  It is working fine if response.dateOfBirth is 08-11-1987. If i pass 1987-08-11 then the users date of birth is decreased by 1.

Comment: Javascript engine parses date based on the current locale if a string is passed to it. So we should avoid string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AngularJS like you're applying in your tags. You can use $filter to make the date like you want. In your case it would be:

```
$scope.datestring = $filter("date")(data.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

More information on $filter(date) you can find [here](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html)

EDIT:

So if I understand correctly you have a date that says: 10-12-2015 and you want to output it as 2015-10-12? Do you use javascript datepicker to get your dates or...? When I put a date in with a date picker the date looks like this:

```
Mon Oct 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

This variable is called: data.date. After this I use this to filter the date to your needs, which is yyyy/MM/dd.

```
$scope.datestring = $filter("date")(data.date, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

And the output is 2015/10/12. I don't get any weird numbers :(

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet @Jelmer We have been using the $filter in agnular to format. Following is my code- $filter("date")(new Date(response.dateOfBirth), "yyyy-MM-dd");  It is working fine if response.dateOfBirth is 08-11-1987. If i pass 1987-08-11 then the users date of birth is decreased by 1.

Comment: Thanks Jelmer. The issue im facing occurs when i try it with new Date(date.date) in $filter. I found one workaround using regex to skip the $filter if the input already matches the required format.